# Why does Hex-rays thinks that 32bit PE is 16bit?

Tags: ida, decompilation

I'm using IDA 6.1 32-bit version.

I'm pretty new to IDA and Hex-rays decompiling. My goal is to generate some C source from a 32-bit PE executable. I know this file is 32-bit PE executable. I've looked at the header struct in a hex editor and confirmed that it has the PE header segment. When I dissassemble the file in IDA Pro, it recognizes that it is an x86 PE executable file.

Further, IDA produces the following output after analyzing the header segment:

```
; Format      : Portable executable for 80386 (PE)
; Imagebase   : 400000
; Section 1. (virtual address 00001000)
; Virtual size                  : 011DAC9D (18721949.)
; Section size in file          : 011DB000 (18722816.)
; Offset to raw data for section: 00001000
; Flags 60000020: Text Executable Readable
; Alignment     : default
; OS type         :  MS Windows
; Application type:  Executable 32bit
```

However, when I select a function and attempt <kbd>F5</kbd> to open the Pseudocode window, I am greeted with the unhelpful message:

> Decompilation failure: FFFFFFFF: 16bit functions are not supported
>
> Please refer to the manual to find appropriate actions

So, I [referred to the manual](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/failures.shtml#10), which is also unhelpful:

> The message text says it all. While the decompiler itself can be fine
>   tuned to decompile 16-bit code, this is not a priority for now. May be
>   in the future it will support 16-bit code.

The thing is that this isn't 16-bit code. What am I doing wrong?

---

*PS If I need to provide more information to help in answering this question, please let me know. I'm very new to IDA/Hex-rays and I'm not sure what else would be useful here.*

Comment: A link to a copy of the actual file would help (and have you verified that the file is not corrupted?)

Comment: I can run the file so it's not corrupted. I don't have permission to paste a copy of the file. I might be able to paste bits and pieces of information if you steer me in the direction to what you are looking for. I'm mainly interested in understanding why Hex-rays thinks this is a 16bit application, when it is clearly 32bit.

Comment: When you view the segment in the Segment View (Shift+F7) does the AD field show 16 or 32?

Comment: I found a application which does this exactly, every function (30000 of them) is `FFFFFFFF: decompilng 16bit functions are not supported` seems to be some obfuscator that tricks IDA?

Comment: AD in fact does show 32

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to figure out what's going on given excerpts from the disassembly, such as an affected function or the beginning of the segment ...

Comment: Having the binary string of such a function would indeed be very helpful. Can either of you supply such a function?